# How to make .hover work properly in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I'm trying to make something like this:

display an icon - on hover becomes a text - on mouseout becomes an icon again.

Here's what I have (which does not work right):

html:

```
<p class="fcc"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp fa-lg"></i></p>
```

CSS:

```
    .fcc-hover {
    font-family: "Unica One", sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: grey;
}

    .fcc {
        margin-top: -37px;
        font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #BADA55;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.fcc').hover(
      function() {
        var newText = $(this).text('A Project for freeCodeCamp');
        newText.hasClass('.fcc-hover');
      }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('.fcc-hover');
        $(this).html(<i class="fa fa-freecodecamp fa-lg"></i>)
      }
    );
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## fixing the example

I got your example working in a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fvz70ne4/

there are a few smaller issues with your example:

- jquery `hasClass(...)` only **checks** if an element has the given class and returns true or false.
- `hasClass(...)`, `addClass(...)` and `removeClass(...)` do not take a selector like `.some-class` or `div#someId`. these functions only take a class name, as a string, which does not feature a leading dot.
- the html uses fa-free-code-camp, the js uses fa-freecodecamp. i have neither of theese so i used fa-code instead.
- the mouse-out function lacks quotes around the `<i...></i>` content, which is a script error.

## css specificity

after fixing all of theese the hover works, but the fcc-hover styles do not.
using the debug tools to inspect the p element shows whats going on:

hovering over the icon adds the fcc-hover class
[image: fcc and fcc-hover classes are set]

but the .fcc-hover style rules are ignored
[image: fcc-hover ignored in favor of .fcc]

this is because of **css selector specificity**

specificity decides which selector wins when they have conflicting styles, like "20px text in green" and "10px text in grey"

.fcc and .fcc-hover have the same specificity because they are both 1 class selector. i wont explain this whole topic here, but the basic order is "ID selectors" `#someID`, class selectors like `.fcc` and finally type selectors like `p`

one id will win over any number of class selectors, but in each category more selectors win, so 2 class selectors are stronger than one class selector.
when two selectors are the same, the order in the css decides. .fcc comes last, .fcc wins.

To fix this i used ".fcc.fcc-hover" because 2 class selectors is stronger than 1

**Flickering**
changing the font-size makes the text flicker back and forth because the element changes under your mouse. to avoid this you have to make sure the element size and position does not change because of the fcc-hover class.

Comment: It works perfectly now. And I learned a lot. Thanks for taking the time to explain all this stuff.